# How to convert from 2s complement values to binary?

Tags: binary, conversion

I am trying to build a calculator that can perform addition and subtraction and works like a real calculator(ie, you press the first number, than the operation, then the second number, and press = to get the answer). My problem is that when I subtract, it gives me the 2s complement of the answer. How can I convert from 2s complement to binary, using a machine?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Two's complement **is** the most common used binary format. Or are you talking about negative numbers? Which would be *signed* two's complement versus *unsigned* two's complement.

Comment: Can you give an example of the result you expect and the result you actually got?

Comment: Well, I tried 7-4 and got -2, and I tries 4-7 and got -4. Also, I am trying signed 2s complement to binary.

Comment: You don't. 2's complement IS binary.

Comment: you may have posted an XY question .... you asked about what you believe to be the solution to the problem, but the solution may be misguided .... perhaps you should be asking about why 7-4 and 4-7 both return negative results

Comment: Let's start from the beginning. When you say you're "trying to build a calculator", what have you actually got, then? A big pile of logic gates on a breadboard? VHDL/Verilog inside an FPGA or on a simulator? Sketches on a sheet of paper? When you "subtract", what are you actually subtracting on?

Comment: I'm using Logisim to try and make a schematic to put on a breadboard later. And also, I'm talking signed 2's complement, like converting from 1111 to 1001 for -1?

Comment: No, don't convert! 1111 ***is*** -1 in signed two's complement. What you are doing is converting it to a non-standard number format. The standard arithmetic logic will not work with your number format. (I deleted a previous comment which may have been misleading...)

Comment: @NipDip - "1001 for -1". That is called sign magnitude. It is not generally used as it complicates any calculations. As others have stated it is normally best to use 2's complement and only convert to sign magnitude (and probably decimal) when you actually need to display the value.

Comment: It seems that you are using few bits to hold your values in. 7-4=-2 happens when you are storing your numbers in such a short format that you get rollover or the value bits extend into the MSB and make it look like a negative number. Try using 8-bit numbers and doing 7-4 again. You've got to choose a suitably large-enough storage format. Like yours, all calculators suffer from overflow/underflow limitations. Unlike yours, they've chosen a storage format big enough for their biggest numbers plus a big margin.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, per se.

It is an exploration of how the results of `7 - 4 = -2` and  `4 - 7 = -4` could happen.

```
 7  0000 0111               0000 0111    7         0000 0111    7
-8  1111 1000             + 1111 1100   -4       + 1111 1011    4 inverted
                          ------------           ------------
 4  0000 0100               0000 0011    3         0000 0010    2
-5  1111 1011       

 2  0000 0010               0000 0100    4         0000 0100    4
-2  1111 1110             + 1111 1001   -7       + 1111 1000    7 inverted
                          ------------           ------------
-4  1111 1100               1111 1101   -3         1111 1100   -4
```